# Python object deletion detection

Tags: c++, python, oop, wrapper, swig

I am building a Python wrapper for a swig interface for a C++ program.

I am interested in knowing if there is a way for a Python object to "know" how it was deleted. The idea is simple, if the object was deleted by the garbage collector the wrapper would do nothing to the underlying C++ object, but if the user deleted the object on purpose (``del object) then the wrapper would detect that and un-reference the underlying object so that it also get deleted.

I tried googling about this already, but could not find anything. The only thing I found is that (apparently) `__del__` is called by both the garbage collector and the del command, and it seems that there is no way to distinguish which one called it.

Hoping someone proves me wrong!

Comment: The issue here is that ``del`` only removes a reference, it doesn't assure the object is deleted - so really all of the deletions are done by the garbage collector.

Comment: You are wrong. As Lattyware mentions, `del` only removes a reference, the object may live happily ever after, or may become unreachable. In any case, only the automatic memory management invokes `__del__`, but it's not guaranteed to. In fact, there are many circumstances where defining a `__del__` *prevents* cleanup (i.e. it's not called). See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

Comment: @delnan: Interestingly enough, PyPy breaks circular references by picking one object to delete first at random, `__del__` hook or not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that shows how insanely implementation-defined these things are. You really can't rely on anything. For example, CPython will repeatedly call `__del__` if `__del__` resurrects (e.g. stores in a global) the object, but PyPy will only do it once. PyPy also won't honor a `__del__` attached to individual objects if the class does not define a `__del__` method. Don't ask me why I know these obscurities o.O

Comment: I quite agree; I only mentioned PyPy as an example to *point out* that GC behaviour is implementation dependent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And it's a good example! My comment wasn't intended as counter argument or something like that.

Comment: I dont really want to focus on __del__ and I read the documentation about circular references too. So I am right there is no way to achieve what I want? not even some smart hack?

Comment: Nope. GC deallocation is never deterministic (in Python as well as in virtually all other languages with GC), and finalizers are never guaranteed to run (again, the same is true in many other environments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPython uses reference counting to track object lifetimes. Thus, *all* deletions are done by the garbage collector.

For example, the following code creates *two* references; the `__del__` hook only is called *once*, after the second reference to the object is deleted:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __del__(self):
...         print "Bye bye!"
... 
>>> spam = Foo()
>>> bar = spam
>>> del spam
>>> del bar
Bye bye!
```

Thus, there is no way to detect an individual `del` statement through the `__del__` hook; it is always only called by the garbage collector.

Note that certain python implementations (most notably cpython), do *not* clear objects with a `__del__` hook that are part of a circular dependency. This does not apply to all implementations, but it bears remembering.

In any case, the use of reference counting to implement object deletion and garbage collection is itself an implementation detail, and non-CPython implementations could (and do) handle object deletion differently altogether.

Comment: Bonus points for discussing multiple implementations (and treating CPython as the exception). But then the first sentence doesn't fit in, as it only applies to CPython, not all Python implementations. Refcounting is so far in the real of implementation details that practically all implementations that aren't directly derived from CPython don't do it.

Comment: @delnan: There, added a `C` to clarify. Since the OP is talking about creating a C++ swig wrapper for a library for python we are certainly dealing with CPython here.